# Unable to check a checkbox inside a <div> but works perfectly well outside

Tags: php, html, css

I am unable to check the checkbox in the below code.  If `<input type="checkbox..` is placed outside the `<div>` it works fine and not inside the `<div>`

Any idea why.

```
<div id="SEL">

  <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:30px; background-color:#FF5300; bottom:1px;">

     <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" style="position:relative; top:5px; left:10px;">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `position: relative;` and `bottom:1px;` on the `div`?

Comment: its working fine here `http://jsfiddle.net/KgQhZ/`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QnfNN/ Works fine for me...

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't understand, but what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. I can check the checkbox just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4ugPj/

If you want to check the checkbox by clicking on the orange area, make it a LABEL element and not a DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/4ugPj/1/

Comment: Strange but true, when using `top:` it does not work,  but on jsfiddle it does work.

Answer (score 1):

use label because , the  element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles the control.

The for attribute of the  tag should be equal to the id attribute of the related element to bind them together.

```
        for example

         <div id="SEL">
         <label style="display:block; position:relative; width:100%; height:30px; background-color:#FF5300; bottom:1px;" for="check">
         <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" style="position:relative; top:5px; left:10px;" id="check">
         </label>
         </div>
```